# Allow cross origins in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cross-domain

sorry for the repeated question but I'm stuck at it.

CORS issue is not getting resolved from any of my code. I tried many possible ways to solve CORS issue but it didn't.

```
    const app = express();

// Middlewares
app.use(express.json());
app.use(morgan('dev'));

// Access-Control-Allow-Origin
/* app.options('*', cors());
app.use(cors()); */

app.use('*', (req, res, next) => {
  // console.log({ message: 'in middleware' });
  /* req.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = 'http://localhost:3000';
  req.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS';
  req.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] =
    'Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Authorization'; */
  console.log({ headers: req.headers });

  next();
});

var corsOptions = {
  origin: 'http://localhost:5000/api/v1/',
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200,
};

// API routes
app.get('/api/v1/', (req, res) =>
  res.status(200).json({ message: "Welcome to the Radical's API" })
);
```

Every time it shows error
[image]

As you can see, I tried multiple ways to solve it, research about it as much as possible, but it's not get solved then I commented. After trying every possible way, now I'm here to present my situation.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this code in your response and I hope it will work

```
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
```

Comment: Thanks for suggesting me. I tried this also but it didn't solve that error

Comment: There is a nodejs package called cors. You can use this.

npm install cors
const cors = require("cors");
app.use(cors({
    origin: '*'
}));

Answer (score 0):

Configure cors for your node js app, in origin insert frontend server url.

```
var corsOptions = {
    origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
    optionsSuccessStatus: 200 
}

app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

(insert this code after app.use(morgan('dev'));)

Answer (score 0):

There is a nodejs package called cors. You can use this.

```
npm install cors

const cors = require("cors");
   app.use(cors({
   origin: '*'
}));
```